# Need to Show Names of Related Files as Checkbox Group in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, files, screen-flow

I am creating a flow in which end users can select files to copy from one record to the other. I have been able to do this using ContentDocumentLink as the object for the record choice set, but I need to show the file name (title) on the screen component for the user to select from, so they know which files they are selecting. However I can't figure out how to do this. I can show one Content Document Title, but not multiple as I can't figure out how to set up the elements to pull all the Content Documents related to the record.

I am using a Get Records element to get all ContentDocumentLinks related to the record (LinkedEntityId = recordId). Then I am trying to use either a Get Records or Record Collection variable to get the Ids of all the Content Documents that are tied to those ContentDocumentLinks but am hitting errors.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: shouldn't the Get Records on ContentDocumentLink allow you access to the parent ContentDocument.Title field (file name)?

Comment: It can, but then how do I display those titles as choices in the screen?

Comment: try using [UnofficialSf.com Execute SOQL Query](https://unofficialsf.com/a-graphical-soql-query-builder-for-flow/) to fetch CDL + parent ContentDocumentTitle in one call

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got your collection of Content Documents (using a loop or the SOQL action from the comments etc.), you can use a Datatable component
The [official one](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_data_table.htm&type=5) will probably meet the need here but there's also an [unofficial one](https://unofficialsf.com/datatable-lightning-web-component-for-flow-screens-2/) that has more features.

I think this will be a lot easier than record choice sets

Comment: The standard `datatable` component does support inline editing.

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove the inline editing example but I can't find any evidence that inline editing is currently supported in the standard datatable.

Comment: It's [in the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation).